# What is the difference between KPR() and DSM()

Tags: debugging

I am learning advanced theming for which I am using *Devel* Module kpr() and dsm() functions to print the arrays on the page for finding variables. So I want to know, What is the main difference between kpr() and dsm() functions? And which one is the best for which condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Devel there are various formatters you can use to dump variables. But the main difference of `dsm()` is, that it uses `drupal_set_message()`, which displays the output in the message array via a session, so that the information is preserved between different requests of the same user. This is helpful for debugging code, which doesn't result in a html page to display a normal var dump, for example a form submit. The disadvantage is, that `dsm()` sometimes produces the output asynchron, not when you expect it, which can lead to false conclusions.

Comment: But sometimes one of the function is not working. I have installed devel on my fresh installation kpr() is working while the dsm isn't working.

Comment: As I've described this depends on when the code runs you want to debug. Most times both work, but there are cases only one of them works. Or none of them, then you need an IDE and Xdebug.